# Is there a workaround to allow strings to mutate in JS? Or to declare complex CSS as NOT strings?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, string, immutability

Any ideas how to refactor given example to allow array elements to mutate due to changes in config object? (The only saviour that comes to my mind are CSS variables, but it's still 2018…) As I state in a comment in code, these are quite long and nasty CSS gradient declarations, which I really don't know how to declare other way then as strings. Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
const config = {
  foo: 42,
  bar: 123,
}

// Very simplified example. in reality, these are complex CSS gradient rules
// with multiple template strings in. Nasty stuff:

const arr = [`foo: ${config.foo}`, `bar: ${config.bar}`];

const doStuff = () => {
  config.foo += 1;
  config.bar += 1;
  console.log(arr[0]); // Does't increment
  console.log(arr[1]); // Does't increment either.
}

document.addEventListener('click', doStuff, false);
```

Comment: The most common solution for things like this is to allow options to be a function. When the application needs to use the option, if it's a function it calls it and uses the result. This allows the option to be dynamic. jQuery UI uses this type of option heavily.

Comment: Back-quote strings are interpolated *once*.  There's no permanent binding between the things referenced via `${ }` expressions and the string values.

Comment: Yes, instead of using a template string, use an object with a `.valueOf` that does what you want. (that's a terrible idea, but.. it'd work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `arr` into a function, then when you need the array, call the function instead:

```js
const config = {
  foo: 42,
  bar: 123,
}

const arr = () => [`foo: ${config.foo}`, `bar: ${config.bar}`];

const doStuff = () => {
  config.foo += 1;
  config.bar += 1;
  console.log(arr()[0]); // foo: 43
  console.log(arr()[1]); // bar: 123
};

document.addEventListener('click', doStuff, false);
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank You! I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Allow the value to be a function, which you call when necessary.

```js
const config = {
  foo: 42,
  bar: 123,
}

const arr = [() => `foo: ${config.foo}`, `bar: ${config.bar}`];

const doStuff = () => {
  config.foo += 1;
  config.bar += 1;
  console.log(typeof arr[0] == "function" ? arr[0]() : arr[0]); // Increments
  console.log(typeof arr[1] == "function" ? arr[1]() : arr[1]); // Doesn't increment
}

document.addEventListener('click', doStuff, false);
```